# Linq2Sql select query with sum, in, left and nolock

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

How I have to code this query in linq using Linq2Sql context?

```
select SUM(ORDERQTY * MULTIPLIER) AS VOL_USD
   from Executions with (nolock)
where TRANSACTTIME >= '2013-08-01 00:00:00'
and TRANSACTTIME < '2013-09-01 00:00:00'
and MTCONTEXT in (5,6)
and ORDERQTY > 0
AND SOURCE = 'INTMT'
and LEFT(SYMBOL, 3) = 'USD'
```

Is it possible to have the generated query by Linq2Sql as same as the pure sql query?

Comment: If it is critical to maintain the command as written, why not issue that query directly? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399403.aspx

Comment: Or use a stored procedure.

Comment: What about sql injection for ExecuteQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                new TransactionOptions {IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted}))
{
    var result = DbContext.Executions.Where(/*...condition...*/).Sum(o=>o.ORDERQTY * o.MULTIPLIER)
}
```